# ¿Como dar de alta mi sitio web creado en Django?

Tags: django, hosting

quisiera saber como subir mi sitio web creado en Django a un alojamiento o dominio? es la primera vez que hago un proyecto en Django y es la primera experiencia que tengo como desarrollador web.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que llevarlo a un entorno de producción, es el entorno proporcionado por el servidor en el que correrá su sitio web para uso externo.
El servidor podría estar ubicado en sus propias instalaciones, pero lo más común y fácil es utilizar un computador alojado "en la nube". Esto en realidad implica que su código es ejecutado en algún computador remoto (o posiblemente un computador "virtual") en el centro (o centros) de datos de su compañía de servicios de hosting. El servidor remoto normalmente ofrecerá un determinado nivel garantizado de recursos de computación (es decir, CPU, RAM, memoria de almacenamiento, etc) y de conectividad a Internet por un cierto precio.

A este tipo de hardware de computación/comunicaciones accesible de forma remota se le denomina Infrastructure as a Service o Infraestructura como Servicio (IaaS). Muchos proveedores de IaaS ofrecen la opción de preinstalar un sistema operativo en particular, sobre el cual se debe instalar el resto de componentes de su entorno de producción. Otros permiten seleccionar entornos plenamente configurados, con incluso configuraciones de Django y servidor web establecidas.

Algunos desarrolladores elegirán la mayor flexibilidad ofrecida por una IaaS frente a una PaaS, mientras que otros valorarán el reducido coste general de mantenimiento y la mayor facilidad de escalado de PaaS. Cuando se está empezando, la instalación del sitio web en un sistema PaaS es mucho más sencilla.

Este es un tutorial para desplegar django en el servicio en la nube de Heroku.
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Deployment